# How to generate a 2D int array using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to generate a `int[][]` using Java 8 streams.

This is what I have done so far:

```
objects.parallelStream()
            .map(o -> o.getPropertyOnes()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(t-> t.getIndex())  //<-- getIndex() returns int
                    .mapToInt(i -> i)
                    .toArray())            //<-- here I have a Stream<int[]>
            .toArray();                   //lost here
```

At the end of outer`.map()` I have a `Stream<int[]>`, but not sure how to convert that to `int[][]`. Please suggest.

Comment: are you looking for  flatMap?

Comment: @Eugene No, don't want to flatten the collection, rather want to create a 2d int array.

Comment: how would you convert a Stream<int[]> to int[][]? Can you provide and example? Even better show us your input and the desired output, it's unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: @Eugene that is precisely my question :)

Comment: You have to use `toArray(int[][]::new)`.

Comment: Instead of the two step `.map(t -> t.getIndex()) .mapToInt(i -> i)`, you can use straight-forwardly `mapToInt(t -> t.getIndex())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you can simplify the `map().mapToInt()` to `mapToInt(t-> t.getIndex())` (maybe you should use a method reference like `<type>::getIndex`).

As you said you have `Stream<int[]>` after the `map` stage. Then you only need to provide an array generator function like:

```
int[][] array = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                      .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, i).toArray())
                      .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Output:

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still need to wait couple of minutes to accept it. One question though, I tried to do `toArray(int[]::new)` for the inner map, i.e. instead of  `.map(t-> t.getIndex()).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()`, tried this:  `.map(t-> t.getIndex()).toArray(int[]::new)`, but it didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @SayanPal Well you have a `Stream<Integer>` this cannot be stored int an `int[]`. `Stream::mapToInt` returns an `IntStream` which provides a `toArray` method which returns an `int[]`. This is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [`toArray(generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method that helps us to specify a return type by an `IntFunction<T[]>` function:

```
int[][] a = Stream.of(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{4, 5, 6}).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

instead of [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--), which returns `Object[]` regardless of an incoming type in a `Stream` (invokes `toArray(Object[]::new)` internally):

```
Object[] a = Stream.of(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{4, 5, 6}).toArray();
```

---

If you are interested in, behind the scenes, all of this have the following look:

1. forming a `Node` [an `ArrayNode` in our case] (an immutable container for keeping an ordered sequence of elements) from a `Pipeline` of the previous stage;
2. array size calculation by using the node size (`node.count()`);
3. getting a new empty array with a needed length by our `IntFunction<T[]>` generator (`i -> new int[i][]` or simply `int[][]::new`);
4. copying from the node to this array and returning the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate 2D array of sequential number of n X n where n in the degree.

```
int n = 4;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n - 1)
        .boxed().map(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(x * n + 1, (x + 1) * n)
            .boxed().toArray()).toArray()));

Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```